# Apache Redirecting All Sub directory Sub Folders Back to Root Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-rewrite, directory

I have a website stored in a root folder. example.com correctly brings me to the website stored in /var/www/mainsite. I want to put multiple websites in sub folders. so example.com/website1, ..2, ..3 etc. To do this i have used an alias since website1 is not stored within /var/www/mainsite.

```
Alias  /website1 /var/www/website1/public/
```

This code only works for the home page. If i go to example.com/website1 it correctly loads the homepage, but if i visit example.com/website1/css it redirects me to example.com/css. This shouldnt be happening. Any url i click on the sub site either brings me to the 404 page of the main site or to some other directory on the main site, but not the sub site. How can i stop apache from doing this. My .htaccess file in /var/www/website1/public is blank. the main website has bit .htaccess file, but since website1 is in a different folder the main site shouldnt even be looked at.

I am currently using subdomains, so im trying to change this to use subdirectories instead.

Im using centos 6 with apache and a php website

Comment: Resolved the issue based on this task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062290/set-rewritebase-to-the-current-folder-path-dynamically

Answer (score 3):

you need  check up **DocumentRoot** settings, in the httpd [mod alias doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html),

> if you are creating an Alias to a directory outside of your DocumentRoot, need to explicitly permit access to the target directory

```
Alias /image /ftp/pub/image
<Directory /ftp/pub/image>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```